# How to pull information from a URL into my swift app

Tags: ios, json, swift, url, screen-scraping

I want to firstly say I am a complete newbie to swift (and to coding in general). I want to pull a some information from a URL (ie: list of sports fixtures) into one of the viewcontroller views in my app. I have looked up various threads which reference kanna and JSON but as I mentioned, I am new to this so it's a bit out of my understanding just yet.

Can anyone provide some simple steps or know of some videos/documentation which I can read up on this to achieve this?

Thank you,

Comment: I used this free video course to learn iOS networking, it should show you everything you need to know to get started.. https://www.udacity.com/course/ios-networking-with-swift--ud42. or another option would be to learn to use [alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple parts to your question.

You need to fetch the data from the remote server, then you need to parse it. For the first part, downloading, you can use `NSURLSession` (renamed `URLSession` in Swift 3.

I have a sample project called [Async_demo](https://github.com/DuncanMC/Async_demo/tree/master/Async_demo) on Github that demonstrates using `URLSession` to download data.

For parsing the JSON you can use `JSONSerialization`, which makes it quite simple to convert JSON data to Swift objects. You should be able to search on Swift `JSONSerialization` to find examples here on SO or elsewhere.

You can also use a third party library like `SwiftyJSON` or `AlamoFire` to do the JSON parsing (and the downloading, for that matter.)

Using `URLSession` and JSONSerialization isn't that hard, however, and it's a good exercise in learning how to use Apple's excellent API documentation in Xcode and learn the application frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) for this answer which I a really nice framework to check out whenever you are interacting with web APIs in Swift

You'll want to start by creating a custom model that you can use to map your JSON data to when you receive it, I'm going to call it `Fixture`. I don't know which API you're using or what your model needs to contain so I'll just make some things up

```
struct Fixture {
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?

    init(from dict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
        // We'll this out later
    }
}
```

Then you need to create a function using Alamofire to call the API and get a response. This is a really simple function without any parameters or headers.

```
Alamofire.request(/*endpoint url*/, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.prettyPrinted, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
     if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
        if let JSON = response.result.value {
           if let response = JSON as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
              // This is where to take the values out of the JSON and cast them as Swift types. 
              //For this example I will imagine that one fixture is returned in a dictionary called "fixture"
              if let dict = response["fixture"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                  let fixture = Fixture(from: dict)
              }
           }
        } 
     }
  }
```

So that's a really simple example. Depending on the exact structure of the API response it will look different. If you update your question with the endpoint you will be calling I can update this answer with more help.

As for the `init` method in your `Fixture` model we can now update it to look like this:

```
init(from dict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
    id = dict["id"] as? Int
    name = dict["name"] as? String
    // Again these will need to be changed to accomodate the exact response
}
```

Comment: Don't use NSDictionary in Swift. Stick with Swift dictionaries.